# Multiple numbers before a noun

Tags: грамматика

Similar to one of my [previous posts](https://russian.stackexchange.com/q/12190/6816), I am wondering what case is used for nouns preceded by numbers of different nature (when there is some discrepancy over which number, or an approximation).

This is because numbers like 1 or 21 are different from numbers like 2, 3, and 4, which are, in turn, different from the rest in which case is used (any, s. gen., and pl. gen., respectively).

Ex. 1: один или два (год?)(года?)

Ex. 2: три или пять (года?)(лет?)

**Which way is correct? Is there more than one correct way?**

Comment: I think два или три года would mean: either two years or three years (definitely one choice or the other), whereas if you want to say "approximately two or three years" it would be два-три года (or 2—3 года). So "discrepancy over which number" and "approximation" would be expressed differently. Maybe a native speaker can confirm?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In short, the last one takes precedence:

> один или два года
>   три или пять лет
>   etc.

**UPD**. Well, as Russian language has free word order, I'd better put it another way: **the closest** number decides. For example,

> Три года или пять
>   Три или лет пять
>   Лет пять или три
>   etc.etc.

Comment: *"Три или лет пять"* - так нельзя говорить. Зато можно вот так: *"Года три или лет пять"*

Comment: @PavelMayorov Почему ж нельзя-то? Если слово ("года") легко восстановить из контекста, то его вполне можно и пропустить. В живом языке вообще много чего можно.

Comment: @Matt Потому что из "три или лет пять" совершенно непонятно чего три. "Три года" совсем не единственный вариант. Да и само по себе звучит коряво.

Comment: @Alex.S "понятно" или "непонятно" - это зависит от контекста. Если контекст позволяет, то будет вполне понятно и ничуть не коряво. И вообще, прежде чем сказать "нельзя", нужно включить воображение, и сразу станет понятно, что на самом деле очень даже "льзя". Тут уж не Бог весть какая мудреная фраза.

Comment: @Matt Если фраза звучит нормально только в контексте, то и приводить ее нужно вместе с контекстом, иначе для изучающего язык никакой пользы. А то в контексте можно что угодно сказать. "Три или вода закипела", например. Только никто не станет приводить  эту фразу в качестве понятной.

Comment: От трех до пяти.

Comment: "Три или пять лет". I wouldn't say neither "три или лет пять", nor "года три или лет пять". If it really sounds weird it's better to include both numerals, both nouns.

Answer (score 3):

i disagree with the chosen response, its example phrases although understandable diverge from the standard usage and good style

in my opinion the rule is as follows:

A. when two numerals call for the same noun but in different numbers (sing. & pl.), only the first one is spelled out whereas the second is implied

> Ex. 1: один или два (год?)(года?)

**`(один) год или два`**

B. when two numerals call for different nouns, both nouns are spelled out

> Ex. 2: три или пять (года?)(лет?)

**`три года или пять лет`**

---

and also it's important to remember that a Russian noun for the word `year` varies depending on the declension of a numeral

N - *1 `год`, *2 - *4 `гОда`, *5 - *9 and round numbers `лет`
G - *1 `гОда`, *2 and onwards `лет`
D - *1 `гОду`, *2 and onwards `годАм`
А = N
I - *1 `гОдом`, *2 and onwards `годАми`
P - *1 `гОде`, *2 and onwards `годАх`
L(ocative) *1 `годУ`, *2 and onwards `годАх`

Comment: Would you say the difference between "один год или два" and "один или два года" is like the difference between "a year or two" and "one or two years"?

Comment: yes, that's a pretty apposite parallel, the difference is stylistic, where one of the phrases sounds awkward or less neat